# How many multisets of length $d$ of a set of $n+1$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics

The number of multisets of length $d$ of a set of cardinality $n+1$ is
$${n+d}\choose{n}$$

This number is, among other things, the dimension of the vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in the variables $x_0,\ldots,x_n$.

What are the most immediate ways to obtain this? Is there a simple proof by recurrence? What about a less elementary proof which you find particularly elegant (and easy to remember)?

Comment: The usual [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) argument is about as simple as anything.

Comment: Something's wrong here. The number of strings of length $d$ over an alphabet of $m$ symbols is $m^d$. Now put $m=n+1$. Multisets are something else.

Comment: Dear @MarcvanLeeuwen, I edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention dimension of the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$, you might appreciate the following point of view.

The [Hilbert-Poincaré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Poincar%C3%A9_series) series of the graded vector space $K[x]$ is clearly
$$
  \sum_{d\in\Bbb N}T^d=\frac1{1-T}=\sum_{d\in\Bbb N}\binom{-1}d(-T)^d.
$$
Here as usual binomial coefficients with arbitrary upper index are given by
$$
  \binom nk=\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{k!},
$$ 
and those with negative integer upper integer index are related to ordinary ones by
$$
  \binom{-n}k=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}k.\tag1
$$

Since $K[x_0,\ldots,x_n]\cong K[x]^{\otimes(n+1)}$ as graded vector spaces, it follows that its Hilbert-Poincaré series is
$$
  \left(\frac1{1-T}\right)^{n+1} =\sum_{d\in\Bbb N}\binom{-n-1}d(-T)^d
  =\sum_{d\in\Bbb N}\binom{n+d}kT^d.
$$
Using $n+1$ rather than $n$ is just a trick to make the final answer come out marginally simpler.